# How to get Doctrine 2 to return a DateTime as a string?

Tags: mysql, datetime, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with Doctrine 2.5 and DateTime field.

I have several DateTime fields in my database and have never had any problems with them in Doctrine 1.2

Right now I'm upgrading my application to Doctrine 2.5 and I'm having a problem with the QueryBuilder and DateTime fields.

Here's my query:

```
$data = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u.id, u.user_id, u.datecreate')
    ->from(self::CART_TABLE, 'u')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult(HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

And here's the result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [user_id] => 16
    [datecreate] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-03-06 20:02:26.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
        )

)
```

Doctrine 1.2 returns:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [user_id] => 16
    [datecreate] => 2015-03-13 18:22:35
)
```

The variable in the Entity is declared as:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="datecreate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $datecreate;
```

If I change the 'type="datetime"' to 'type="string"' it does work.

I actually need the return to be a string and not a DateTime object. How can I achieve that? Is changing the entity the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing all the getters and setters to "string" instead of "\DateTime" and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can change methods, like

```
public function getDatecreate()
{
   return $this->datecreate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: Changing the entity's getters doesn't work for me. Unless I have to do something different in the query as well...

Comment: Than, answer to your question is: changing the entity is the only way

Comment: Oh man... Ok, thanks!
It's so weird, I have seen your answer being THE answer to other similar questions by other people, and it always works for them...

Comment: this is ancient history, but:  I do think this approach could get you in some trouble if your application also involves forms and hydrators that expect this getter to return a DateTimeInterface. This may be a case where the solution ends up being more work than some other solution, like formatting the returned DateTime yourself further up the application stack.